# Python requests POST command is not following 302 redirect

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, https, python-requests

When passing a POST request to a website via requests, it is failing to complete and will wait indefinitely.

I have reviewed the behaviour in Fiddler and I can see that the POST request is returning successfully with a `302` redirect. However, Requests continues to wait and will never continue although the packets have returned.

I'm stuck on how to diagnose this as I get no solid error and the packets appear to return, any help will be much appreciated.

The post request is built as follows:

```
loginData = 'data=45B892A0F9C127FB0A052CB&cid=1000'
s.post(url, verify=rVerify, headers=headers, data=loginData)
```

I have tried allow_redirects as both True and False with no success.

Here is the request and response in Fiddler:

[image: fiddler result]

Update header details:

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
```

Update:

- I have tested just using the URL and the command will still hang.
- I have also attempted a GET request and this also hangs.

Comment: What's on the `headers` variable?

Comment: In the header I set the following: User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Content-Type, Connection

Comment: Did you figure it out. I really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem appears to be with Python3 and the httplib libary not being able to parse the header returned from the server.

Here is the the issue: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3098

To get around this I have just changed to Python 2 which doesnt need to parse the header in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making use of the POST object to manually redirect the next URL which is returned with the 302.

```py
loginData = 'data=45B892A0F9C127FB0A052CB&cid=1000'
response = s.post(url, verify=rVerify, headers=headers, data=loginData)

next_url = response['location']

# do your next step here using the returned URL
```

The 302 should be returning a URL to redirect to in the header as the value of "Location". As shown above you'll find this in the Response object dictionary.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302, https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

Comment: I am unable to do anything after the post command as Requests waits indefinitely. The code following I have a get request with the new URL but it is never run.

Comment: Did you guys figure it out ? really need it